# Laravel: How to verify DB::transaction function is working or not?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have used `DB::transaction` function in my controller like this,

```
public function store(){        
    $plant = new Plant;

    DB::transaction(function()
    {
        Plant::create(request(['name','plant_code','place']));    
    });    
}
```

I want to know the way I have used the function is ok and i need to verify is it working correctly?

Comment: AFAIK transactions works that way - once exception is thrown everything in transaction will be rolled back. If you are making any db queries inside your Plant::create() function it should be rolled back on any exception. However, if you catch exception I wouldn't expect that it'll be rolled back. Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#database-transactions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#database-transactions) illustrate you have two choices :

1. **Automatic transaction with `Closure` :**

> You may use the `transaction` method on the `DB` facade to run a set of
>   operations within a database transaction. If an exception is thrown
>   within the transaction `Closure`, the transaction will automatically be
>   rolled back. If the `Closure` executes successfully, the transaction
>   will automatically be committed. **You don't need to worry about
>   manually rolling back or committing while using the `transaction`
>   method**

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    // Interacting with the database
    DB::insert(...);
    DB::insert(...);
    DB::insert(...);
});
```

2. **Manually Using Transactions :**

If you would like to begin a transaction manually and **have complete control over rollbacks and commits**, you may use the beginTransaction method on the DB facade:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
```

You can rollback the transaction via the rollBack method:

```
DB::rollBack();
```

Lastly, you can commit a transaction via the commit method:

```
DB::commit();
```

The manually use of the transactions is linked to the **`try catch`** block like this :

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    // Interacting with the database
    DB::insert(...);
    DB::insert(...);
    DB::insert(...);

    DB::commit();    // Commiting  ==> There is no problem whatsoever
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();   // rollbacking  ==> Something went wrong
}
```

For testing the transaction you can run your example without throwing any exception ==> expected result : all fine the Plant will be created.

And if you throw an exception the transaction will be rollbacked and the Plant will not be created in the database :

```
public function store(){        
    $plant = new Plant;

    DB::transaction(function()
    {
        Plant::create(request(['name','plant_code','place']));    
        throw new ModelNotFoundException("Just for testing :)");
    });    
}
```

Add `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;` at the top of the controller ;)

Comment: It's looking great. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Can you tell me what the usage of `DB::rollback();` is? Without it nothing will commit if we have an exception in try.